# Add '#items' in a loop

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add the following code in java script into a loop.

```
 $('#items').find('input').prop('disabled', this.checked);
```

i want to change the 'items' variable as '#items1', '#items2', '#items3' and so on as a loop.

This code has already worked in this part of my code

```
var checkList = document.getElementById('list1');
```

when added to loop to get 'list1', 'list2', 'list3'

```
var checkList = document.getElementById('list'+list[i].value);
```

but it doesnt work  for the 'items' in previous code may be because there is a # in front. Please help me with it.

Comment: You shouldn't be using IDs, you should be using classes for something like that

Comment: what is the `list` variable that you're using here ? `list[i].value`

Comment: it comes from a list of subjects i have added in an array.

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code; for instance where is list[i] coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Guyss I myself solved the problem. I first got the variable value to a another variable and put it in the function.

```
var itemId = list[i].value;
```

I put this inside the function.

```
$(function() {
   $(document).on('change', '#IsAssociation', function() {                        
   $('#items'+itemId).find('input').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
   $('#items'+itemId).find('li').toggleClass('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var checkList = document.getElementById('list' + (i + 1));
```

Or for best use, try using class instead of `id`, give all item class called for example: `itemClass`, then you can get all items:

```
var checkLists = document.getElementsByClassName('itemClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is once you using the following codes:

```
$('#items').find('input')
```

you got not only one DOM elements. So, you need to using jQuery.each after finding all 
'input' elements, and then do what you want.